# Why in an Angular project do he components stop being visible after compilation?

Tags: angular

While working with Angular, sometimes after compilation my components or some HTML elements that I write on the app template are not visible but if you inspect the page, even if there isn't any error, the elements are there.
Like for example, this is the app template which doesn't gets rendered:

```
<div 
  class="card card-strong disable-text-selection"
  collapse-on-click
  #cp
  [collapsed]="collapsed"
  [class.collapsed]="cp.collapsed">
  <i class="md-icon collapsible-indicator"></i>
  <div class="collapsible-section"></div>
</div>
```

This is the app ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  collapsed = false;
}
```

It's very very simple, yet nothing happens

This is another example with a component

Component template:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <form class="px-4 py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Username</label>
        <input 
          type="email" 
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Type your email please"
          id="signInFormEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input 
        type="password" 
        class="form-control"
        id="signInFormPassword"
        placeholder="Type your password please">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input 
          type="checkbox" 
          class="form-check-input"
          id="rememberMe">
        <label 
          for="rememeberMeCheck" 
          class="form-check-label">Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
  </form>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">New around here? Sign up</a>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
```

Component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sign-in-form',
  templateUrl: './sign-in-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in-form.component.css']
})
export class SignInFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

App template

```
<sign-in-form></sign-in-form>
```

app ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Form } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  active = false;
}
```

Comment: probably your component does not mounted.please share some code.

Comment: How do you compile your angular application. Do you use angular CLI or custom webpack? Do use use devserver to lifereload browser?

Comment: @Akash_Kumar I've just edited the question and added the code, thanks

Comment: @simplygood I use the CLI, and no, no deserver is used

Comment: Did you check if there are any global styles that are preventing your component from being displayed in your browser like display: none